# Is it possible to split expression with OR, to two cases?

Tags: c

I want to use a switch statement, and my condition fot the if is:

```
if (userInput%2 == 0 || userInput != 0)
```

Can I get two cases from this code to execute different actions for `userInput == 0` and different one for `userInput == 0`

```
case ?:

case ?:
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make *any* sense as written. I think you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: `if (userInput%2 == 0 || userInput != 0)` == `if(true)` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You are already using `if` why do you want to use `switch` or vice versa

Comment: Rephrase your question. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, because the value sets satisfying the two conditions *overlap*. Specifically, all even numbers satisfy both parts of your conditions. That is why you cannot perform different actions without deciding first which part of the condition takes precedence.

You can play a little trick with fall-through inside the `switch` statement, like this:

```
switch(userInput%2) {
    case 0:
        // Do things for the case when userInput%2 == 0
        ...
        // Note: missing "break" here is intentional
    default:
        if (userInput == 0) break;
        // Do things for the case when user input is non-zero
        // This code will execute when userInput is even, too,
        // because of the missing break.
        ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions please how can I solve this with switch since i have to? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: do you need break in default case?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan A `break` at the end of the `default` is optional because the `default` is the last case in the `switch`. It wouldn't change the code the compiler produces.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just split the `if` statement

```
if (userInput%2 == 0) {
    // something
}
else if (userInput != 0) {
    // something else
}
```

Note that the order of tests will be important as all non-zero even numbers satisfy both tests.

Comment: I have to use switch in this task :/ @simonc

Comment: Ok, then assuming you don't have a typo in your question, dasblinkenlight's answer will work for you